# How do I trim spaces and indentations after traversing a DOM tree?

Tags: org-mode, indentation, whitespace, formatting, xml

The following traverse the dom tree and provide an iterative custom formatting. However during the formatting, there are empty spaces and indentations which I needed to trim.

```
;;; This is where the formatting takes place. 
(defun org-tag (x depth)
  (let* ((node (dom-node x)) (stars (make-string depth ?*)))
    (pcase (dom-tag node)
      ((and (pred stringp) str) str)
      ('comment '())
      (tag (format "%s %s %s {%s} \n"
                   stars
                   tag
                   (pcase (assq-delete-all 'data-field
                                           (dom-attributes node))
                     ('() "")
                     (attributes
                      (concat "("
                              (mapconcat #'format-attribute attributes
                                         ", ")
                              ")")))
                   ;; (mapconcat #'test-tag (dom-children node) "")
                   (mapconcat (lambda (child)
                               (org-tag child (1+ depth)))
                    (dom-children node)
                    ""))))))

(defun macro-orgify (tag-entries)
  "returns the formatted dom tree"
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert tag-entries)
    (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (org-tag (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body))))))

(defun format-attribute (attribute)
  "Format a single attribute."
  (format "%s=\"%s\"" (car attribute) (cdr attribute)))

;;; a test
(let ((myskel "<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
    </head>
    <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
    <body>
        <header data-table=\"testtable\">
            <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
            <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
        </header>
        <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
            <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE 
                  this multiline comment 
                   -->
               <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>"))
  (macro-orgify myskel))
```

After parsing, I have the following results

```
"* body  {
        ** header (data-table=\"testtable\") {*** h1  {Skeleton Screen} 

            *** h1  {Skeleton Screen} 

        } 
** div (class=\"wrap\") { Sample Text *** p (class=\"format\", data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\") {Welcome to this page} 

            *** div (class=\"flex-grid generic-card\") {
                
                **** div (class=\"card loading\") {Text } 

                
               **** div (class=\"card loading\") {} 

            } 

        } 

    } 
"
```

How do i trim the spaces and indentations?

Comment: Trim the string returned in the first (p)case as follows `(string-trim-right str " *")`. (And don't forget to pass 2 args to `org-tag` ;)